# Images management for shopping cart

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a Shopping Cart (Cake PHP) and have 700 000 products. I need to store images for all the products to show on website. The total space of all the images is 600 to 700 GB.

How should I manage these images? Should I use any third party to manage images or should I store the images locally and show it?

Comment: Depends on the size of your server (do you have enough space to store all the images) and whether you want to be reliant on a 3rd party for your site to work properly.  I would personally keep them on your own server as it will be easier to maintain and you won't need some third party api to access them

Comment: Okay, will the performance be same in both the cases ?

Comment: depends on your third party and your server provider